# Inequality to ensure three positive real numbers are each less than one

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers. Is there an inequality that can ensure that $a, b, c$ are each less than 1 without ruling out valid cases (i.e., not being incomplete)?

For example, the inequality $abc < 1$ is unsound because it does not prevent the case where $a = 10, b = 0.1, c = 0.1$. On the other hand, the inequality $a + b + c < 1$ is sound but incomplete because it rules out valid cases such as when $a = 0.7, b = 0.7, c = 0.7$.

Perhaps a pointer to a general theory regarding this matter: how to produce an inequality to determine that 2 or more positive real numbers $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ are each less than a given real number $y$ in a sound and complete manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to express $\max(a,b,c) < 1$ which is equivalent to $\max(\max(a,b),c) < 1$
Since 
$$
\max(a,b) = \frac{|a-b|+a+b}{2}
$$
then your inequality is
$$
\max(\max(a,b),c) = \frac{1}{4} (\left| a+b+\left| a-b\right|-2 c \right| +\left| a-b\right| +a+b+2c) < 1
$$
and clearly you can generalize this to any number of variables,
for example, $\max(x,y,z,t)$ is equal to $\max(\max(x,y),\max(z,t))$ or $\max(\max(\max(x,y),z),t)$ and so on.